# How to change react-select tag border radius

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to override `react-select` styles to achieve rounded multiValue tags.

So I went ahead and edited the `multiValue` style attribute like this:

```js
const customStyles = {
    multiValue: (styles) => ({
        ...styles,
        backgroundColor: blue,
        borderRadius: "50%",
    }),
}
```

The background color works perfectly and the tag becomes blue. However the border radius is always stuck at 2px...

```js
<Select
    options={options}
    styles={customStyles}
    isMulti
/>
```

How to override the default 2px border-radius imposed by `react-select`

Comment: tried exactly what you've done and it worked just fine..

Comment: Try using `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I was overriding the background color of the `multiValueLabel`, which was somehow hiding the overridden border-radius in `multiValue`. Removing the `backgroundColor` attribute from the `multiValueLabel` solved the issue.